# How to properly decode accented characters for display

Tags: c#, encoding, special-characters, decoding

My raw input file text file contains a string:

```
Caf&eacute (Should be Café)
```

The text file is a UTF8 file.

The output lets say is to another text file, so its not necessarily for a web page.

What C# method(s) can i use to output the correct format, `Café`?

[Apparently a common problem](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Caf%26eacute%22)?

Comment: `&eacute` should have a `;` terminator char following it to render the é properly.

Comment: That'll be a problem then!  Cause our raw files doesn't contain the any terminators...Dam.

Comment: Yup, that will be a big problem... you'll have to "massage" the data somewhat in order to use the provided solutions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Caf&eacute;")`? it returns 538M results

Comment: Thanks but this nor this works: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Caf&eacute")

Comment: @Fixer You need a semicolon on the end of your entity `&eacute;`

Comment: @Matthew you mean like: string s = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Caf&eacute;"); ?

Answer (score 2):

This is HTML encoded text. You need to decode it:

```
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
```

UPDATE: french symbol "é" has HTML code "`&eacute;`" so, you need to fix your input string.

Comment: Nope sorry doesn't work?  string decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Caf&eacute");

Comment: Thats because you should add ';' to the end of your Caf&eacute;

Answer (score 2):

You should use [SecurityElement.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) when working with XML files.

`HtmlEncode` will encode a lot of extra entities that are not required.  XML only requires that you escape >, <, &, ", and ', which `SecurityElement.Escape` does.

When reading the file back through an XML parser, this conversion is done for you by the parser, you shouldn't need to "decode" it.

EDIT: Of course this is only helpful when **writing** XML files.

Comment: This is a pretty cool way for sanitizing input for Html as well. When using HttpUtility.Encode you also encode accented chars wich will be shown encoded in inputs (not desired). Using this only 5 elements will be shown as encoded, witch is acceptable to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
string utf8String = "Your string";

Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(utf8String);

byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, unicode, utf8Bytes);

char[] uniChars = new char[unicode.GetCharCount(unicodeBytes, 0, unicodeBytes.Length)];
unicode.GetChars(unicodeBytes, 0, unicodeBytes.Length, uniChars, 0);

string unicodeString = new string(uniChars);
```

Comment: Thanks but does'nt work: string decodedString = utf8.GetString(utf8.GetBytes("Caf&eacute"));

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`. Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("test", 
            HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("caf&eacute;")));

        Console.WriteLine(doc);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```