# How can I "decode" the `&#231;` value in C#

Tags: c#, linq, diacritics

I have a string with diacritic text in it. The string is being encoded in the code behind to `&#231;` and then being displayed on a web page as `&#231;`. I need the string to be rendered, but it's not clear to me how to do that with C# on the back end.

I tried `.ToString()` and `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, but the web page is still displaying `&#231;`, instead of *ç*, which is how it should be displayed.

How can I "decode" the `&#231;` value in C#?

The code is below. The field is `CountryName`.

```
var countryList = (from x in listDataRow
                   join y in genericNameValueMetadataItemList on x.Field<string>("CountryISO") equals y.Value.Text into countryGroup
                   from item in countryGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultGenericNameValueMetadataItem)
                   select new Country
                   {
                       CountryISO = x.Field<string>("CountryISO"),
                       CountryName = (!item.Title.Text.IsNullOrEmpty()) ? item.Title.Text : HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(x.Field<string>("CountryName"))

                   }).OrderBy(x => x.CountryName).ToList();
```

The following code works just fine in a console application for me. Could the problem be because of the LINQ syntax?

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Cura&#231;ao"));
Console.WriteLine(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Cura&#231;ao"));
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem was that I needed to wrap the `item.Title.Text` code with the HtmlDecode function as well as the `x.Field<string>("CountryName"))` code.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: The code is added.

Comment: That question has an accepted answer that does not work.

Comment: Are you sure what `x.Field<string>("CountryName")` return `"...&#231;..."` text and not something else?

Comment: I got it from the debugger.

Comment: People are saying this question is a duplicate of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875940/how-to-properly-decode-accented-characters-for-display". I guess maybe it is, but that question has an accepted answer that does not work.

Comment: If you do `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("...&#231;...");` then result will be `"...ç..."`. How do you see the wrong output? Where do you output result?

Comment: I see the output in the debugger and in a dropdown list. The letter is part of a longer string. `Cura&#231;ao`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to wrap the `item.Title.Text` code with the HtmlDecode function as well as the `x.Field<string>("CountryName"))` code.